# Review posts and remaining dailly votes

Tags: discussion, review-queues, voting, rate-limiting

StackOverflow (I assume it is the same across all other sites) won't let me review First Posts and Late Answers because I have reached my daily up/down limit.

But reviewing is not tied to voting. I have reviewed posts without voting them up or down, so why the limitation?

The specific error message is "Daily up/down vote limit reached; come back in 3 hours."

Comment: My previous votes on the day were not on the Review queue. My votes were on questions/answers, not on reviews.

Comment: Reviewing in the first posts and late answers queue **is** tied to voting, in that voting is an action you can take in the queue. We cannot give you *extra* votes just because you wanted to use them both for posts outside and inside the queue.

Comment: I am not asking for extra votes to be used in the queue. What I am asking is to be possible to review even though my voting limit was reached. I would still be able to edit the post, add comments, indicate that I would like to skip or indicate that I am done with the review.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos but if you aren't allowed to vote (because you ran out), then you can't effectively review in those queues.  By continuing to review you would be doing a disservice to other users who want to review those posts too but can't because you reviewed them.  You'd also be doing a disservice to the users of the posts you review since you can't vote on them and they would be getting an incomplete review of their post.

Comment: @psubsee2003, your argument is only valid if you HAD to vote up and down on your review. Have you ever reviewed a post and didn't vote it up or down?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos but you are missing the point.  Once you review the post, no one else can, so if the post is vote worthy and you can't vote, then you failed to do the review completely.

Comment: I don't think so, voting and reviewing are orthogonal. I can review and not vote up and down, and I can vote up/down without reviewing. Tying them up is an artificial (and wrong IMO) construct. In fact, forbidding up and down votes during reviews would not change reviews at all, which are about the question, and not your opinion on the post. Reviewing is absent of opinion, while up and down voting is opinion based.

Comment: You are not paying attention to what people are saying. I was sort of annoyed the first time I discovered this limitation, too - then I realized it made complete sense. You *can* review without voting, but what do you do if you encounter an item where the obvious correct thing to do is vote, and you can't? Yes, there are definitely such items. It is completely not true that you shouldn't be voting during reviews.

Comment: @neminem, I *am* paying attention to what people are saying, and I value the opinion of others who disagree even more when they have moving arguments. My only disagreement is that the reason of the limitation is very weak.

Comment: This a perfectly valid question! I don't see any grounds for downvoting at this scale regardless of whether there is a valid reason to rate-limit voting on first-posts and late-answers. The question itself is valid and good, as evidenced by the engagement.

Answer (score 11):

**One** of the primary functions of the First Post and Late Answer review queues is to vote on worthy posts.  If you can't vote, you shouldn't be allowed to participate because you cannot fulfill one of the primary functions of the queue.

Reviews in the First Post and Late Answer review queues is carefully rate limited to prevent any posts from getting too many extra views.  This is because extra views translate into extra votes that the post may not necessarily have received organically.  As such, each post is only reviewed by an extremely limited number of users.  IIRC each post is only available to be reviewed once in First Posts and Late Answers.

If you are allowed to review posts in these queues when you don't have all of the necessarily tools available to you (such as when you have run out of votes), then you can't fairly review the post.

For example, if you are given 5 posts to review after you have run out of votes, those are 5 posts that have been reviewed but could not possibly have been voted on even if they deserved a vote.  As such, those 5 posts received incomplete review, and suffered because the lack of votes did not get the post the attention it deserved.  Whereas 5 other posts that were reviewed by users who could vote may have had complete reviews and possibly benefited from the complete review.

The only fair way to handle this issue is to prevent reviewing in the review queue when you do not have the necessary tools for the specific review queue.

If you really want to continue to review posts when you run out of votes, just hang out in the ["Newest Questions" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) and look for posts that need attention.  I guarantee you will find plenty of posts that need attention, such as editing or commenting.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* - and don't dare say "but I won't get credit for the review to get closer to earning a badge" because if that is the sole reason you want to review, then stop reviewing</sup>

Comment: But the system *doesn't* block you from the Close Votes, First Posts, or Low Quality Posts queues when you're out of close votes for the day.

Comment: @AndrewMedico when I am out of close votes, I can't review in the close vote queue.

Comment: You are in luck that I ran out of votes for today :)

Comment: I am out of close votes right now and the system is not keeping me out of the Close Votes queue.

Comment: So, why I am allowed to edit question/answers if I am out of votes?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos because editing is not tied to voting.  Why are you not understanding that one of the primary purposes of those review queues is to vote on posts the deserve to be voted on, and if you can't vote you can't review properly.  And if you can't review properly then your review is incomplete.

Comment: I got that, @psubsee2003, but if the only difference between editing and reviewing is the voting, then voting should be mandatory during review.

Comment: @AndrewMedico if you can continue to review posts for closure after votes then something is broken.  I'll edit that section out since it is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos no because there are posts that don't deserve votes.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes but when you review you can also just give helpful comments or answer the question, **you don't have to vote**. If they are a poor question you can offer advice via comment or flag if it's a really poor quality question.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I don't disagree there, but the whole point is the rate limiting, and I don't think people are grasping that.  If you run out of votes that it is impossible to vote on a post even if it deserves it.  And if you are the only reviewer then the post is not getting a complete review.  The only way to allow you to review without the ability to vote is to allow for multiple reviews (probably at least 5), and then every first post or late answer is going to potentially get an extra 5 votes that it would not have received had it not gone into the review queue.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek don't misunderstand me... if there was a way to allow for fairness (in terms of views and votes) to allow for multiple reviews, I'm all for it.  New users need extra guidance on how to user Stack Overflow.  But the purpose of voting is to assess the quality of posts so if posts are not getting a fair shake when it comes to voting, then we are doing a disservice to the community as a whole.