# Why are Review Queues inaccessible when vote limit reached, but not flag limit?

Tags: discussion

A few days ago, I used up all of my votes in a day and was barred from further reviewing. This makes sense in the context of [this MSO answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261058/2615940), which suggests that one of the primary functions of reviewing first posts and late answers is to guarantee those votes get a SO-experienced set of eyes on them fairly quickly so they can get up or down votes. Can't vote anymore? Then you can't "fulfill one of the primary functions" (from linked answer), so you can't do any more reviews. I vote frequently while reviewing, so I suppose that makes sense.

However, I would contend that an even more important purpose of reviewing new user's posts is so bad posts can be flagged and closed or deleted as quickly as possible.

Today, I went on a flagging spree through the [driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/driver) and [drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drivers) tags because people like to post driver installation or driver-seeking questions there. I used up all my flags, and surprisingly, I still have access to the queues!

Is there any reason we are barred from reviewing when we run out of votes for the day, but not when we run out of flags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because most people don't run out of flags. But more importantly, because you can still be useful in /review if you can vote, even if you can't flag... Voting sends a strong, immediate signal to everyone else on the site, while flagging is between you and mods / reviewers - it's plenty useful, but it's not the *only* useful thing you can do in the First Posts and Late Answers queues, the only ones where voting matters.

The exception here would be spam. Generally, you want to flag spam as spam and do *nothing else* to it. If you can't, then skip & let someone else flag it. That's kind of an edge-case though, as is the limitation's relevance as a whole - most people don't run out of flags very often.

Comment: To add to your points, 3k+ers can close questions instead of flagging.

Comment: I wonder why you should not downvote spam as well.

Comment: It's just pointless, @Johannes.

Comment: Doesn't explain why I shouldn't do something pointless :P

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong - you absolutely *should* do something pointless. But voting pointlessly while Tetris still exists is a missed opportunity for pointlessness.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn The Community user downvotes for you, making it pointless for you to spend one reputation point, only to get it back again.

Comment: I think the quality of the action diminishes quickly, if no flags are left. And it's frustrating to read through a whole bunch of nonsense, only to find out, you can't do anything about it (and no, I don't think downvoting is a solution here).